# Truncate string in html form

Tags: javascript, html, freemarker, netsuite, truncate

I am trying to truncate a string that is generated from a NetSuite (CRM) freemarker tag.

The tag returns:   **C100000 Company Name : FirstName LastName**

I would like to truncate everything up to and including the : and ideally, I would also like to removee the lastname part too, but happy to leave it if it's too complex.

This code will be run within an html email form and will be used to personalise the **Dear "customer firstname"** component.

Thanks in advance!

Brett

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: HTML emails don't run Javascript.

Comment: You'll need to do the truncation in the code that composes the email, not in the email itself.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of this email template.  The system runs the template and merges the freemarker tags and runs the javascript which generates the email content.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
tag.split(": ")[1].split(" ")[0]
```

the first split puts "FIRSTNAME LASTNAME" into the second part
the second split puts "FIRSTNAME" into the first part

Comment: Thanks for that. Given I am not a coder, how would that look like start to finish.  Cheers, Brett

Comment: That's not what stackoverflow is for, sorry. You might want to try the Jobs section for hired help.